# iOS 6: UIView transform animation, no animating happening on device working on simulator

Tags: animation, uiview, ios6, transform

I have created an application iOS 6 targeted to iOS 5. The animation is working fine on simulator but giving problem on device having iOS 5. Please suggest me something. Thanks in advance.

code :
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{answerImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(imageView.transform, 0.0f, 0.0f);} completion:^(BOOL finished){ if(finished)  NSLog(@"Finished !!!!!!");}];

Answer (score -1):

Autolayout really messes with animations. Try disabling autolayout.